# Python - Comparar Listas, utilizando condições para determinar Inicio e Final da Pesquisa

Tags: python

*Introdução*: Programa tem **1 Listas** e **1 Conjunto**:
Lista = **Entrada de Dados**; Conjunto: **Dados de Comparação**

```
lista_entrada = ['BBB','AAA','CCC','DDD','EEE']
    print()
    for item in lista_entrada:
        print("item")

lista_bd = {'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE','FFF','GGG','EEE'}
```

***Problema:***

Como comparar a Lista com o Conjunto;

Imprimir os valores iguais, a partir do item: **"AAA"**, não imprima valores anteriores ao item **"AAA"** contidos na lista. Imprima até o item **"EEE"**

Tentei algumas coisas, mas não sei lidar muito bem com laços de repetição e funções de busca em listas ou conjuntos :/ Aí sempre acabo caindo nesse problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lista = ['BBB','AAA','CCC','DDD','EEE']
conjunto = {'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE','FFF','GGG','EEE'}

aaa_encontrado = False
for item in lista:
    if item == "AAA":
        aaa_encontrado = True
    if aaa_encontrado and item in conjunto: #Imprimir os valores iguais,
        print(item)                         # a partir do item: "AAA"
    if item == "EEE":   # Imprima até o item "EEE"
        break # sai do for
```

Comment: Obrigado!
Eu realmente estava complicando tudo, vou me focar em resolver as coisas de modo sutil e eficaz
Obrigado pela paciência